# Не происходит автораспаковка в методе String.valueOf(), при использовании в качестве аргумента метода - возвращаемое значение обобщенного метода

Tags: java, строки, int

Когда пытаюсь использовать в качестве аргумента метода `String.valueOf()`, возвращаемое значение из обобщенного метода `<T> T testMet1(int a)`, то получаю ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class [C (java.lang.Integer and [C are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') at test.main(test.java:4)`

Исходный код:

```
    class test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          test2 tstOb = new test2();
          String tstStr = String.valueOf(tstOb.testMet1(1));
       }
    }

    class test2 {
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       <T> T testMet1(int a) {
          Integer tstInt = 5;
          return (T) tstInt;
       }
    }
```

То что возвращает метод `<T> T testMet1(int a)` можно понять выполнив следующий код:

```
    class test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          test2 tstOb = new test2();
          Class tstCl = tstOb.testMet1(1).getClass();
          System.out.print(tstCl);
       }
    }

    class test2 {
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       <T> T testMet1(int a) {
          Integer tstInt = 5;
          return (T) tstInt;
       }
    }
```

Результат выполнения будет следующий:

> class java.lang.Integer

Следовательно метод `String.valueOf(tstOb.testMet1(1))` получает объект типа `Integer` в качестве аргумента и должен вести себя так, как если бы в него напрямую передали данный объект, но такого не происходит.

Comment: Тут проблема не в `Integer` и не в `valueOf()`, а в том, что класс `T` при таком использовании неизвестен. И любой каст к нему будет давать ошибку.

Comment: Во время выполнения, `T` определяется как `Integer`, это можно увидеть по тому что в самом сообщении об ошибке указан класс `Integer`. Также если создать ссылочную переменную типа `Class` и присвоить ей значение `tstOb.testMet1(1).getClass()`, то хранить эта переменная будет данные о классе `Integer`. Также если прямо в методе выполнить ручную распаковку `(int) tstOb.testMet1(1)` то будет работать.

Comment: Да, насчёт ошибки кастинга `Integer` и `T` - это я, кажется, не прав. Но тем не менее, в том месте, где мы этот метод вызываем, мы всё равно не знаем, что такое `T` - собственно, это вы и видите, когда передаёте результат в метод `valueOf()`. Вы правильно заметили, что можно самому привести к `(int)` и ошибок не будет. Тогда и в `valueOf()` тоже можно передавать, приводя к `(int)`, и тогда ошибки тоже не возникнет.

Comment: Про ручную распаковку я и имел ввиду, что ее можно произвести при передаче аргумента. Но вопрос в том, почему автораспаковка не выполняется. На этапе компиляции, конечно мы не знаем что такое `T`, но факт в том что на этапе выполнения это известно. Также если поменять параметр в обобщенном методе `<T> T testMet1(int a)` на `<T> T testMet1(T a)`, то тоже все будет работать. Хотя и в этом случае очевидно что на этапе компиляции `T` неизвестен.

Comment: Возвращаемый тип метода - это `T`, он неизвестный: ведь вы, к примеру, не передаёте параметров типа `T` в метод, по фактическому типу которых тип `T` мог бы быть распознан. Но возвращаете именно его, а для внешнего мира он просто `T` - вот использующие методы (в нашем случае - `valueOf()`) и не знают, что с этим делать. Ручное приведение помогает, но это уже нечестное "знание" о типе - вы ведь приводите к тому, что сами в методе и написали.

Comment: Если верить ошибке и переходу по колёсику мышки в Intellij Idea в метод `valueOf()`, то он вообще пытается привести результат к массиву символов `char[]`, выдавая в итоге ошибку.

Comment: По факту я вижу то что возвращается объект типа `Integer` но не происходит автораспаковка его в тип `int`, из-за чего метод не может корректно выполниться. Опять же, то что на этапе выполнения, методу известен `T` это факт, выше описал почему.

Comment: Что возвращается компилятор определяет по вызывающему коду. А вызывающий код предлагает только `char[]` или `Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обобщённый метод всегда возвращает объект и никогда примитив. Из всех перегрузок `String.valueOf` только две работают с объектами:

> ```
> public static String valueOf(Object obj)
> public static String valueOf(char[] data)
> ```

Компилятор должен выбрать из них один. По правилам он выбирает наиболее конкретный тип - это `char[]`. Вы получаете ошибку приведения `Integer` к `char[]`.

Поправить можно указав нужный тип (`Object`) явно:

> ```
> String.valueOf((Object)tstOb.testMet1(1))
> ```

**P.S.** Автораспаковка работает когда известен конкретный целевой тип. В случае `String.valueOf` конкретный целевой тип не известен (много перегрузок) - автораспаковки не будет.

Comment: При передаче непосредственно объекта типа `Integer`, происходит автораспаковка. Вследствие чего используется вариант метода  `valueOf(int i)`

Comment: Добавил фразу про автораспаковку. Она не работает, так как в вызывающем коде нет явного упоминания `int`.

Comment: По этой логике, если мы передаем в метод`valueOf()` объект типа `Integer` то будет ошибка. Но при прямой передаче ошибки не возникает.

Comment: Вызов `valueOf(Integer i)` отображается в `valueOf(Object o)`, который вызывает `o.toString()` (объект сам знает как сделать из себя строку). Ошибки не будет.

Comment: Почему тогда аналогичная ситуация не происходит. Метод `<T> T testMet1(int a)` возвращает объект типа `Integer`, но выходит то что используется `public static String valueOf(char[] data)`.

Comment: `<T> T testMet1(int a)` - здесь нет упоминания `Integer`. Компилятор обрабатывая код вызова не смотрит в тело метода. Всё что он знает - будет возвращаться объект. Какие перегрузки `valueOf` принимают объект? Дальше всё в ответе.

Comment: То что обобщенный метод, возвращает в объект класса `Class` данные о типе Integer, дает мне повод думать что на этапе выполнения известен тип `T`. Следовательно и в методе `valueOf()` будет известен этот тип. Из чего следует что метод `valueOf()` должен реагировать аналогично тому, как если бы в него напрямую передали объект типа `Integer`.

Comment: Вы путаете динамическое и статическое связывание. Ваш пример - это статическое определение нужного метода в процессе компиляции. Ваш комментарий - динамическое связывание, или полиморфизм

Comment: То есть компилятор на этапе компиляции статически выбирает вариацию  `public static String valueOf(char[] data)` из-за того что нету явного указания на целевой тип, а потом по факту пытается в этот метод засунуть `Integer` ?

Comment: да. компилятор трактует этот так - есть некий метод `testMet1`, который возвращает что-то, что является наследником класса Object. и есть 2 метода, которые работают с типом/подтипом класса Object. выбор методов идёт от наследника к предку, ну собственно char[] и подходит по всем параметрам, так так подкапотно является наследником Object.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае обобщённый тип `<T>` используется для *метода экземпляра* класса `test2`, но сам этот тип остаётся неизвестным для компилятора.

Можно либо указать, что класс `test2` является обобщённым и создать *сырой* экземпляр, как в начальном коде:

```java
class test2<T> {
    // ...
}


test2 tstOb = new test2();
String tstStr = String.valueOf(tstOb.testMet1(1));
```

Также можно указать *любой* тип (кроме `char[]`) при вызове метода в необобщённом классе:

```java
String tstStr = String.valueOf(tstOb.<Integer>testMet1(1));

// ...
class test2 {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    <T> T testMet1(int a) {
        Integer tstInt = 5;
        return (T) tstInt;
    }
}
```

По сути этот тип требуется только для компилятора, а кастинг как таковой выполняться не будет, и будет вызван общий метод `String.valueOf(Object o)`, а не для массива `char[]`.

Comment: Способы как можно исправить ситуацию я знаю. Мне интересна причина того почему код ведет себя подобным образом.

Comment: "... можно указать любой тип" - кажется, это не совсем верно, так как если в качестве типа передать `char[]`, то вернёмся к той же ошибке. Подойдёт любой тип, кроме этого.

Comment: Да @Byb, верно, исправил.