# чем отличается T func0() {} от <T> T func() {} в java?

Tags: java, шаблоны

чем отличается `T func0() {}` от `<T> T func() {}` в java?

Comment: Это две разные функции. Так как параметры одинаковые (их нет) то что бы они компилировались они должны быть по разному названы

Comment: А есть рабочий компилирующийся пример со вторым вариантом? Вообще, в первом случае конкретный T берется из параметра класса-дженерика, где метод объявлен, а во втором должен определиться по параметрам метода (тут дженерик-метод, а не дженерик-класс), но в данном случае (без параметров метода) я не представляю как можно заставить работать.

Comment: Разве что делать `return null;`, но толку от такого метода никакого

Comment: @insolor недавно был задан вот такой вопрос [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1523806/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-string-valueof-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5). Там есть такой код, и он вполне работает. А в ходе обсуждения даже объяснено, как именно)

Comment: Первая функция возвращает экземпляр с типом `T`, то есть где-то в коде должен быть объявлен соответствующий тип `T` как класс / интерфейс/ энум / кортеж.  Во второй функции `T` означает параметр типа (который по идее должен быть указан в объявлении обобщенного класса `class My<T> {}`), функция является обобщенной.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, тут без контекста нельзя однозначно ответить. Возможны две ситуации:

1. Методы находятся в обобщённом классе с типом `T`
2. Методы находятся в обычном классе

Рассмотрим первый случай:

```
class Byb<T> {

    T func1(T a) {
        return a;
    }

    <T> T func2(T a) {
        return a;
    }

}
```

Первый метод будет использовать тип `T`, передаваемый классу. Вполне естественный вариант, тут всё очевидно.

У второго метода мы явно пишем тип `T`. В этом случае он *скроет* тип `T` у класса и будет использовать свой тип `T`. Можем убедиться в этом на примере:

```
Byb<Integer> byb = new Byb<>();
System.out.println(byb.func1(5).getClass());
System.out.println(byb.func2("Hello").getClass());
```

Результат:

```
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.String
```

Классу передали `Integer`, но в метод со своим типом `T` передали `String`, и тип `T` стал именно `String`-ом.

Рассмотрим второй случай:

```
class Byb {

    T func1(T a) {
        return a;
    }

    <T> T func2(T a) {
        return a;
    }

}
```

Теперь первая функция просто-напросто неверна. Мы не знаем, что такое тип `T`, так как его нет ни у класса, ни явно прописанного у метода. Из-за этой функции код не запустится.

А по второй функции - всё так же, как было описано для первого случая. Будет просто использоваться свой тип `T`.